# How to fix syntax error at semicolon before equal

Tags: python

I am running a code taken from the website

http://foreverlearning.altervista.org/genetic-programming-symbolic-regression-pt-2/

at the bottom of the page.  This is a part when testing treeOperations.py.

To test this code, I run the mainprova.py code that is provided at the bottom of the page after treeOperations.py listing.  I am getting the following syntax error:

```
 python mainprova3.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "mainprova3.py", line 2, in <module>
 import treeOperations as trop
 File "/home/adam/DocumentsNew2/MathCode/SymbolicRegression/WebpageCode   /treeOperations.py", line 23
if choice &lt;= leftNodes:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to python.  I do not understand the semicolon before equal sign.  What it means? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&lt;` is the HTML entity for `<`.  There is apparently some sort of bug in the linked site that is causing things to be HTML-escaped that shouldn't be.  Replace `&lt;=` with `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently copied the code from the GitHub page while looking at the html. Try just cloning the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/fabiochiusano/SymbolicRegressionPy.git
```

Or, if you don't have git, look at the file in 'raw' and then save it, instead of copying it off the nicer-looking page. For example, like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabiochiusano/SymbolicRegressionPy/master/symreg/treeOperations.py

Answer (score 0):

You can go here: https://github.com/fabiochiusano/SymbolicRegressionPy

and click on `clone or download` > `Download zip` to download all the correct code files at once.

[image: screenshot]